# Problem with the rectangle method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in javascript and have a problem with my code. It says NaN whereas I've been checking for a long time and haven't found the problem. Thanks for having a look at it !Here is my code

```js
const a = -10;
const b = 10;
let X = [];
let p = 20;

for (let i = 0; i <= p; i++) {
  X.push(a + i * ((b - a) / p));
}

function maFonction(antecedent) {
  return antecedent ** 2;
}

function methRectangles() {
  let aireTotale = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i <= p; i++) {
    aireTotale = aireTotale + maFonction(X[i]) * (X[i + 1] - X[i]);
  }
  return aireTotale;
}
methRectangles();
console.log(methRectangles());
```

Comment: You take it one too far: `for (let i = 0; i < p; i++) {`

Comment: I suggest breaking down each line into its parts and checking each part. For instance, inside the loop in `methRectangles`, do `console.log(X[i + 1])`. You'll likely find that at the end of the loop, it will log `undefined` when `i === p`, since that's the length of the array. Since `undefined - anything` is `NaN`...

Comment: Your `X[i + 1]` reaches non-existing element at the end of loop iterations -> `undefined` -> `NaN`

Comment: Why did you call `methRectangles()` before `console.log() ?`